# How to Correct this code?

Tags: java

I have to make a GPA Calculator in Java...
User will enter Course names,Obtained marks and Percentages...
and Program will output Grade,Grade Points for all Subjects individually
and then Program will Output Average GPA...
Program will also give remarks about GPA like if it is 4.0....
Excelent will be shown in Output......
I am not asking for Code i just want Proper Guidance that how to solve this like what functions should 
i make or where loops will be aplied?.(this Kind of guidance)?

I have tried like this.....

```
     import java.util.Scanner;

     public class Calc {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter number of a Subjects");
     int nm = sc.nextInt();

     for(int i=0;i<=nm;i++)
     {
      System.out.println("Enter name of a Subject ");
                String Sub1 = sc.next();
       System.out.println("Enter the Obtained marks of a Subject");
                int ObtM = sc.nextInt();


                if(ObtM<40)
                {
                System.out.println("Grade is F");
                System.out.println("GradePoint is 0");
                System.out.println("Remarks=Fail");
                }
            else if(ObtM<=49&&ObtM>=40)
                {

                System.out.println("Grade is D");
                System.out.println("GPA is 1");
                System.out.println("Remarks=pass");
                }
            else if(ObtM<=50&&ObtM>=64)

                {

                System.out.println("Grade is C");
                System.out.println("GPA is 2");
                System.out.println("Remarks=Satisfactory");
                }
            else if(ObtM<=65&&ObtM>=79)

                {

                System.out.println("Grade is B");
                System.out.println("GPA is 3");
                System.out.println("Remarks=Good");

                }
           else if(ObtM<=80&&ObtM>=100)

                {

                System.out.println("Grade is A");
                System.out.println("GPA is 4");
                System.out.println("Remarks=Excellent");
                }
                int percentage=ObtM*100/100;
                System.out.println("Percentage is "+percentage);

                }

            }
```

}

Comment: do your assignments on your own!

Comment: In what way does your current code not work as expected?  Where are you stuck?  We're happy to answer specific questions but we don't offer tutoring services.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful comment

Comment: Only this loop works (ObtM<40).If user enter more than 40 remaining loops does not work

Answer (score 1):

You're programming in an Object Oriented Language, so take advantage of it! I would write a class for homework assignments with the parameters: course name, assignment name, grade, etc. The beauty of this is that you can store all the assignments as an array and loop through displaying what you want to display. All the calculations could be handled in the separate assignment instances.

This organization will help you clean up your code and make problems a little easier to detect. Feel free to read more about this style of coding on the Oracle Documentation.

The reason why only one of your `if` statements works is because you have inverted all of the signs. You're asking your program to identify numbers that don't exist, namely: grades less than a number and also larger than that same number. By switching your less than and greater than syntax, you will achieve what you're trying to find.

Example:

```
if (ObtM <=50 && ObtM >= 64)
```

Becomes

```
if (ObtM >=50 && ObtM <= 64)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statements are completely wrong. `if(ObtM<=50&&ObtM>=64)` would require a number that is *less* than 51 **and** *more* than 63. You want the conditions to be the other way around (`ObtM >= 50 && ObtM <= 64`).

Pay attention to what you write.